Data seemingly not being saved into GridDB partitioned table (No Errors being thrown?)
I have a java program which writes rows into my GridDB table via the NoSQL API. I am properly catching errors and I see in the logs that the data is being stored into my container via multiput, but when I go into the CLI to view the contents of the data, the container is completely empty?
First, here's what the container looks like:
gs[public]> showcontainer LOG_agent_intrusion_exploit
Database    : public
Name        : LOG_agent_intrusion_exploit
Type        : COLLECTION
Partition ID: 22
DataAffinity: -
Partitioned : true
Partition Type           : INTERVAL
Partition Column         : timestamp
Partition Interval Value : 30
Partition Interval Unit  : DAY
Expiration Type      : PARTITION
Expiration Time      : 30
Expiration Time Unit : DAY

Columns:
No  Name                  Type            CSTR  RowKey
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  timestamp             TIMESTAMP(3)    NN
 1  username              STRING
 2  incomingIP            STRING
 3  serverIP              STRING
 4  mtu                   INTEGER
 5  statusCode            INTEGER
 6  cacheHit              STRING
 7  method                STRING
 8  url                   STRING
 9  urlPrefix             STRING
10  urlSuffix             STRING
11  httpVersion           STRING
12  service               STRING
13  riskLevel             STRING
14  headerContentType     STRING
15  bytesReceived         INTEGER
16  bytesSent             INTEGER
17  headerAgent           STRING
18  url2                  STRING
19  url2Prefix            STRING
20  url2Suffix            STRING
21  meta1                 STRING
22  meta2                 STRING
23  meta3                 STRING
24  meta4                 STRING

My log parser is creating a hashmap with the container names as the key name, gathering up all rows, and then using store.multiPut to push to GridDB. for this function, I am doing a simple try/catch block which normally does catch the GridDB errors.
Quick snippet:
                for (RawLog log : logs) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(log.logtype + "~~~~~~");
                        System.out.println("configs.get(log.logtype)" + configs.get(log.logtype));
                        Row row = lp.patternMatcher(proc_container, log, configs.get(log.logtype));
                        if (row != null) {
                            proc_logs.add(row);
                            System.out.println("parsing this row: " + row);
                        } else
                            System.out.println("Could not parse " + log);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Could not parse " + log);
                    }
                }

                containerRowsMap.put(proc_container, proc_logs);

            }
            try {
                db.store.multiPut(containerRowsMap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error with inserting data");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

So, in this case, it seems as though data should be in my table, but when I run a simple query select * from LOG_agent_intrusion_exploit;, i get zero rows back.
I tried foregoing multiput and inserting one row at a time but I get the exact same behavior.

UPDATE: I was able to figure this one out. As it turns out, I had some expiry rules set for 30 days (as in my data rows expire every 30 days) but was ingesting data much older than that (~10 years). And so GridDB was ingesting the data and it was there, it's just that the GridDB cluster was doing its job in expiring the rows, making them unreadable (and possibly deleted, not sure how quickly that process occurs)
So the solution was simply to remove the expiry rules or make them long enough that ten year old data wasn't immediately flushed out.
